# calling function stored as a property in an object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

In my template i'm rendering a v-list using a v-for.

```
<v-list dense>
  <template v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems">
    <v-list-item :key="index" @click.stop="menuItem.function">
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon :color="menuItem.color">{{ menuItem.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>
      <v-list-item-title> {{ menuItem.title }} </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-list>
```

in my script section i'm doing this

```
data: () => ({
    menuItems: [
        {
            title: 'Lijst samenklappen',
            icon: 'mdi-arrow-top-left-thin-outline',
            color: 'grey',
            function: 'collapse'
        },
        {
            title: 'Onderdeel toevoegen',
            icon: 'mdi-plus-circle',
            color: 'green',
            function: 'add'
        },
        {
            title: 'Bestaand onderdeel toevoegen',
            icon: 'mdi-plus-circle',
            color: 'green',
            function: 'addExisting'
        },
        {
            title: 'Dit onderdeel verwijderen',
            icon: 'mdi-minus-circle',
            color: 'red',
            function: 'disable'
        }
    ]
}),
methods: {
    cardClick() {
        this.$nuxt.$emit('set-part', this.tab)
    },
    add() {
        this.$nuxt.$emit('add-part', this.part.PK_R_ASSEMBLY)
    },
    addExisting() {
        this.$nuxt.$emit('add-existing-part', this.part.PK_R_ASSEMBLY)
    },
    disable() {
        this.$nuxt.$emit('disable-part', this.part.PK_R_ASSEMBLY)
    },
    collapse() {
        this.$nuxt.$emit('collapse', this.tab.PK_R_ASSEMBLYDETAILSUBASSEMBLY)
    },
    open() {
        this.$nuxt.$emit('open', this.tab.PK_R_ASSEMBLYDETAILSUBASSEMBLY)
    }
}
```

I've tried several way's to try and call the function by the property value in the object.
No luck

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?
Not all code is displayed, as I don't think it is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your click event like this:

```
 @click.stop="handleEvents(menuItem.function)"
```

And add a new function to your methods object to call functions:

```
methods: {
   handleEvents(funcName) {
     this[funcName]()
   } 
}
```

Comment: Omg, i tried this. but added a dot between this and [funcName], like so: this.[funcName]. Thank you

Comment: @Selage haha yeah js is fun! Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic function like `menuMethod(action, part)` with the following

```js
menuMethod({ action, part }) {
  this.$emit(action, this[part])
}
```

and call it like that in the template

```html
<v-list-item
  :key="menuItem.title"
  @click.stop="menuMethod({ action: menuItem.function, part: menuItem.part })"
>
```

with an update to your object like

```js
{
  title: 'Dit onderdeel verwijderen',
  icon: 'mdi-minus-circle',
  color: 'red',
  function: 'disable',
  part: 'part.PK_R_ASSEMBLY'
}
```